# How Can I Move a File No Matter The User (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

My Problem is that I'm trying to make a Windows Form Application and in I have to move files around
Problem with that is that to move files I need to move within their user directory, meaning

C:\Users"UserName"

I just need to know how to find the "UserName" or how I can move files Within their "UserName" Directory without having to make change the code for every person

hope you get what I mean

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: [SpecialFolder.UserProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` and `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` to get the current user profile path, like so:

```
var userDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

But be aware that this isn't always a good idea, especially if you're dealing with Roaming User Profiles.

> A roaming user works on more than one computer on a network. A roaming
> user's profile is kept on a server on the network and is loaded onto a
> system when the user logs on.

In that case the Microsoft recommended place to store application specific data is the `ApplicationData` directory, which you can access like this:

```
var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```